# Azure DevOps bypass pull request policy not working

Tags: azure-devops

I have enabled the setting for `Bypass policies when completing pull requests` for a user on a specific repo so they can push their changes without getting caught up by the overall branch policy. Unfortunately they still cannot see the option for overriding and merging their pull request. There doesn't seem to be anything else that is set to an explicit `Deny` for any of the groups they are in, all the groups are set to `Not Set`. What else is blocking their ability to override pull request policies? If I set it for myself I can override the pull requests, but I am a project administrator.

[image]

[image]